# What should i return from this async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I am a regular user of Promises in javascript. Now, I want to try async/await. But I am stuck due to half knowledge of async/await.

I have a function using Promise as follows:

```
const asyncRequest = (funcA, b) => {
  // do some syncronous stuff. e. g. console.log
  console.log(b);
  return funcA(b)
    .then((something) => console.log(something))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

I have tried to convert the above Promise based code to async/await:

```
const asyncRequest = async (funcA, b) => {
  // do some syncronous stuff. e. g. console.log
  console.log(b);
  try {
    const something = await funcA(b);
    console.log(something);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

The function conversion looks easy. But I notice that I have `return` keyword in my Promise based code. But in my async/await code, i am confused. What should I return?

**Real Example:**

*Promise based example*

```
const Toast = {};

const createAsyncAction = ({
  asyncRequest, types, loadingPayload = null, showToastOnError = true,
}) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: types.loading,
    payload: loadingPayload,
  });

  return asyncRequest()
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.isMock) { // if mock request
        dispatch({
          type: types.success,
          payload: response.payload,
        });
        return;
      }

      if ([2, 3].includes(String(response.status).substring(0, 1))) { // if request succeeds
        response.json()
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.statusCode === 1000) {
              dispatch({
                type: types.success,
                payload: res.data,
              });
              return;
            }
            dispatch({ // if its a known error by server
              type: types.failure,
              payload: {
                code: res.statusCode,
                message: res.message,
              },
            });
            if (showToastOnError) {
              Toast.error(`${res.statusCode}: ${res.message}`);
            }
          }).catch((error) => { // if response is not convertible to json
            dispatch({
              type: types.failure,
              payload: {
                code: response.status,
                message: error.message,
              },
            });
            if (showToastOnError) {
              Toast.error(`${response.status}: ${error.message}`);
            }
          });
        return;
      }

      dispatch((error) => { // if request fails with some status codes like 404, 500...
        dispatch({
          type: types.failure,
          payload: {
            code: response.status,
            message: error.message,
          },
        });
        if (showToastOnError) {
          Toast.error(`${response.status}: ${error.message}`);
        }
      });
    }).catch(() => { // if request cannot be made due to some internet or connection issue
      dispatch({
        type: types.failure,
        payload: {
          code: 0,
          message: 'Connection issue. Make sure your are connected to the internet and that your API is working',
        },
      });
      if (showToastOnError) {
        Toast.error('Connection issue. Make sure your are connected to the internet and that your API is working');
      }
    });
};

export default createAsyncAction;
```

*Async/Await example:*

```
const Toast = {};

const createAsyncAction = ({
  asyncRequest, types, loadingPayload = null, showToastOnError = true,
}) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: types.loading,
    payload: loadingPayload,
  });

  try {
    const response = await asyncRequest();
    if (response.isMock) { // if mock request
      dispatch({
        type: types.success,
        payload: response.payload,
      });
      return;
    }

    if ([2, 3].includes(String(response.status).substring(0, 1))) { // if request succeeds
      try {
        const jsonResponse = await response.json();
        if (jsonResponse.statusCode === 1000) {
          dispatch({
            type: types.success,
            payload: jsonResponse.data,
          });
          return;
        }
        dispatch({ // if its a known error by server
          type: types.failure,
          payload: {
            code: jsonResponse.statusCode,
            message: jsonResponse.message,
          },
        });
        if (showToastOnError) {
          Toast.error(`${jsonResponse.statusCode}: ${jsonResponse.message}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: types.failure,
          payload: {
            code: response.status,
            message: error.message,
          },
        });
        if (showToastOnError) {
          Toast.error(`${response.status}: ${error.message}`);
        }
      }
      return;
    }

    dispatch((error) => { // if request fails with some status codes like 404, 500...
      dispatch({
        type: types.failure,
        payload: {
          code: response.status,
          message: error.message,
        },
      });
      if (showToastOnError) {
        Toast.error(`${response.status}: ${error.message}`);
      }
    });
  } catch (_) {
    dispatch({
      type: types.failure,
      payload: {
        code: 0,
        message: 'Connection issue. Make sure your are connected to the internet and that your API is working',
      },
    });
    if (showToastOnError) {
      Toast.error('Connection issue. Make sure your are connected to the internet and that your API is working');
    }
  }
};

export default createAsyncAction;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need one!

Any function marked as `async` will always return a promise. Now, if you wanted that promise to resolve to something, then you would need to return a value. However, since you are just doing `console.log`, which has a return value of `undefined`, that's equivalent to returning nothing (since JavaScript will implicitly return `undefined` if there is no specified return value).

From the [`async` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously
>   via the event loop, using an implicit `Promise` to return its result.

So, `async` will implicitly return any returned value from the function wrapped in a `Promise`.

Comment: I will show you my current and past implementation of my real function. Can you then explain me the difference. Let me update my question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please take a look at my real example in the question and then explain the difference?

Comment: @Vishal do you mean they are not functioning the same, but you expect them to?

Comment: Yes, i mean that I expect both of them to function the same. But I am unable to test these functions as I have not the access to other modules of the code.

Comment: They look the same to me. I would actually argue that the first which uses `.then` and `.catch` actually has a bug in it. You don't return the `response.json()` call meaning if the outer promise completes before `response.json()` then you will lose access to the inner promise, potentially then doing things outside the promise block that you didn't want to do until `response.json()` completes. The `async/await` version does not have this problem since you properly `await response.json()`

Comment: And it's not too hard to test the code yourself. Just define the missing functions and run the code locally. Ex: `const asyncRequest = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve());`

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the bug. I will test it using Promise.resolve. That's a good idea. And a big thanks for the helping hand and your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a return. That isn't the cause of the difference in your code. In your example, you need to use `await` when you call funcA(b), since you want to let js do other things while it's resolving.

```
const asyncRequest = async (funcA, b) => {
  // do some syncronous stuff. e. g. console.log
  console.log(b);
  try {
    const something = await funcA(b);
    console.log(something);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to put await in the example. Thanks for noticing that. I have updated the question. Can you please explain me the thing?

Comment: You don't need a return. That was the only functional difference I saw between them which was the underlying problem in your question.

If including `await` didn't fix your problem, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52654940/edit) to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and figuring out the bug in my question. Your answer in the comment is good but the other answer is too good and I cannot accept two answers. Again thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score -1):

Both functions return Promises.

In the first case this is because you are returning a Promise chain. In the second case it is because all `async` functions return Promises, by definition. So the "return a Promise" message is implicit in the second function.

When you return a value from an `async` function, that is the value that the promise is resolved with. If you don't return anything, the promise is resolved with the value `undefined`. In this context, that is actually the value returned in the function `.then((something) => console.log(something))`. This is, of course, `undefined`, so you needn't return anything.